# unable to to run bazel build command

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, bazel, mediapipe

I m trying to execute handtracking android app using bazel and when I run the build command I get this error :

can you help me fix it please

```
ERROR: C:/users/admin/mediapipe_repo/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/formats/BUILD:251:24: C++ compilation of rule '//mediapipe/framework/formats:landmark_cc_proto' failed (Exit 1): clang fai
led: error executing command external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang -gcc-toolchain external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/w
indows-x86_64 -target ... (remaining 57 argument(s) skipped)
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/w'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/std:c++17'
Target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 151.344s, Critical Path: 132.86s
INFO: 160 processes: 128 internal, 31 local, 1 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: You seem to be passing Visual Studio flags to Clang. You will need to show at least how you invoked Bazel and any configuration you did.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a note](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows) in the Mediapipe documentation:

> Note: building MediaPipe Android apps is still not possible on native Windows. Please do this in WSL instead and see the WSL setup instruction in the next section.

This implies that what you are trying to do is currently not possible, sorry. See also [this issue](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/137) for other people in your situation.

Comment: yeah ,probabely that's the reason thank u for ur answer